# ArchLinux on MacbookPro 5.3 EFI single boot with hfs-bless

Tags: arch-linux, macbook-pro, efi

I want to try to install ArchLinux on my macbook pro 5.3 with EFI support, i don't want any other OS but Archlinux. but i am unable to convince Apple firmware to load my custom efi image. What i have done till now.

- I have 2 partitions on GPT 240gb ssd disk

  - /dev/sda1  - 512mb - HFS+  mounted as /boot/efi
  - /dev/sda2  - 230gb - EXT4  mounted as /
- Pacstrapped on sda2 including /boot with Grub. completed my settings locale etc. on /
- Followed all instructions in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#GRUB_standalone configured grub & applied mkinitcpio
- Created EFI with grub-mkstandalone here is full cmdline

> grub-mkstandalone -d /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/ -O x86_64-efi --modules="part_gpt part_apple part_msdos part_bsd" --fonts="unicode" --locales="en@quot" --themes="" -o "/boot/efi/bootx64.efi"  "boot/grub/grub.cfg=/tmp/grub.cfg" -v

- Created /boot/efi/System/Library/CoreServices folder and placed bootx64.efi file in it with SystemVersion.plist (i know i don't need plist file but anyway did it.)
- Then i have compiled [mactel-boot](http://www.codon.org.uk/~mjg59/mactel-boot/mactel-boot-0.9.tar.bz2) in my chrooted env to use hfs-bless

> ./hfs-bless /boot/efi/System/Library/CoreServices/bootx64.efi

No luck. Macbook did not even recognise the EFI to show a bootable source. 
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Well. I don't really know what was wrong to create HFS partitions with gdisk or cgdisk. But just don't do it. I have created the hfs partition with Disk utility & used the original bless of Osx then everything worked like charm. If you are going to install Arch, just before deleting OSX, create an empty hfs+ partition to boot properly, since Apple's EFI implementation is not standards compatible. 
Now i have nvidia chipset problem to deal with.